# ADODB::Recordset: RecordCount fetching each Row

Tags: c++, c, sql-server, oledb, adodb

I try to receive the numer of records for a Select statement and the record set at once.

The Recordset Object offers the `RecordCount` Property for this issue.

It works just fine using a static, server-side cursor, but if i view the events in SQL Server Profiler, I realize, that it seems to fetch every row of the whole recordset, just to count the rows.

On the other hand, I can do a MoveLast on the recordset and the `Bookmark` contains the index of the last row (== Recordcount).
I do not want to use the Bookmark instead of the RecordCount and wonder if someone could explain this behaviour.

If anyone is interessted, I created a small code sample to reproduce it:

```
::CoInitialize(NULL);

ADODB::_ConnectionPtr pConn;
HRESULT hr;
hr = pConn.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ADODB::Connection));
pConn->CursorLocation = ADODB::adUseServer;
pConn->ConnectionTimeout = 0;
pConn->Provider = "SQLOLEDB";
pConn->Open(bstr_t("Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=s11;Initial Catalog=...;Application Name=DBTEST"), "", "", ADODB::adConnectUnspecified);

// Create Command Object
_variant_t  vtRecordsAffected;
ADODB::_CommandPtr cmd;
hr = cmd.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ADODB::Command));
cmd->ActiveConnection = pConn;
cmd->CommandTimeout = 0;

// Create a test table
cmd->CommandText = _bstr_t("create table #mytestingtab (iIdentity INT)");
cmd->Execute(&vtRecordsAffected, NULL, ADODB::adCmdText);

// Populate
cmd->CommandText = _bstr_t(
   "DECLARE @iNr INT\r\n"
   "SET @iNr = 0\r\n"
   "WHILE @iNr < 10000\r\n"
   "BEGIN\r\n"
   "  INSERT INTO #mytestingtab (iIdentity) VALUES (@iNr)\r\n"
   "  SET @iNr = @iNr + 1\r\n"
   "END\r\n"
   );
cmd->Execute(&vtRecordsAffected, NULL, ADODB::adCmdText);

// Create a Recordset Object
_variant_t  vtEmpty(DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND, VT_ERROR);
ADODB::_RecordsetPtr Recordset;
hr = Recordset.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ADODB::Recordset));
Recordset->CursorLocation = ADODB::adUseServer;

cmd->CommandText = _bstr_t(
   "SELECT * FROM #mytestingtab"
   );
Recordset->PutRefSource(cmd);
Recordset->Open(vtEmpty, vtEmpty, ADODB::adOpenStatic, ADODB::adLockReadOnly, ADODB::adCmdText);

// Move to the Last Row 
Recordset->MoveLast();
_variant_t bookmark = Recordset->Bookmark;

// Recordcount
long tmp = Recordset->RecordCount;

Recordset->Close();
pConn->Close();

::CoUninitialize();
```

Is there a way to use the `Recordset` Property, without transferring all rows to the client??

Comment: This doesn't look like C. You might update the language tag for your question.

Comment: As a workaround to get the number of records you can use separate query: select count(*) from table where [conditions]